# grails input tag: placeholder not shown if value is a whitespace

Tags: grails, input, placeholder, gsp

I have an input tag field in my gsp (Grails project) and I want to use a placeholder to show some text when field is empty:

```
<input type="text" name="textField" id="textField" value="${receiptInstance?.patient?.surname} ${receiptInstance?.patient?.name}" placeholder=<g:message code="patient.choose" default="Insert patient..." />/>
```

When I create a new object, `value` is not empty, but it has got a whitespace, so placeholder is not shown.
How can I change this kind of behaviour to use placeholder? Is there a way to eliminate the whitespace in `value`?

Comment: You can't embed a tag like that.  You probably want something like `<input type="text" name="textField" id="textField" value="${receiptInstance?.patient?.surname} ${receiptInstance?.patient?.name}" placeholder="${message(code: 'patient.choose', default:'Insert patient'Insert patient...)}"/>` or <g:textField name="textField" id="textField" value="${receiptInstance?.patient?.surname} ${receiptInstance?.patient?.name}" placeholder="${message(code: 'patient.choose', default:'Insert patient'Insert patient...)}"/>`

Comment: It does not work. Whitespace remains

Comment: Right.  I didn't look close enough and was distracted by the invalid nesting of GSP tags that jumped out at me.  Sorry about that.  I have posted an answer below with several workable options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround can be:

```
<g:set var="myVal" value="${receiptInstance?.patient?.surname?:''} ${receiptInstance?.patient?.name?:''}"/>
<input type="text" name="textField" id="textField" value="${myVal?.trim()}" placeholder='<g:message code="patient.choose" default="Insert patient..." />'/>
```

Note:- Add `'` in your placeholder, as I have added. Or you can use following code as well

```
<input type="text" name="textField" id="textField" value="${myVal?.trim()}" placeholder="${g.message(code: 'patient.choose', default: 'Insert Patient...')}"/>
```

Comment: It does not work as expected...the field has always a whitespace into it...only if I delete it I see the placeholder.

Comment: Sorry I have missed one thing in the code. I have updated my answer. Have a try once again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<g:set var="tmpValue" value="${receiptInstance?.patient?.surname} ${receiptInstance?.patient?.name}"/>
<g:textField name="textField"
             value="${tmpValue.trim()}"
             placeholder="${message(code: 'patient.choose', default:'Insert patient')}"/>
```

If you wanted to get rid of the temporary variable, you could do something like this:

```
<g:textField name="textField"
             value="${(receiptInstance?.patient?.surname + ' ' + receiptInstance?.patient?.name).trim()}"
             placeholder="${message(code: 'patient.choose', default:'Insert patient')}"/>
```

Either way you will need to deal with the literal "null" showing up if receiptInstance?.patient?.surname or receiptInstance?.patient?.name ever turn out to be null.  That is simple enough to do, but is a separate issue and I have left that out to keep the code above focused on the question as asked.

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

You could also use a simple tag to help:

```
// grails-app/taglib/com/demo/PatientTagLib.groovy
package com.demo

class PatientTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']

    static namespace = 'patient'

    def fullName = { attrs ->
        def patient = attrs.patient
        if(patient) {
            def fullNameStr = patient.name ?: '' +
                              ' ' +
                              patient.surname ?: ''
            out << fullNameStr.trim()
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your GSP:

```
<g:textField name="textField"
             value="${patient.fullName(patient: receiptInstance?.patient)}"
             placeholder="${message(code: 'patient.choose', default:'Insert patient')}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some magic of .with() can be used:

```
<input type="text" name="textField" id="textField" value="${receiptInstance?.patient?.with{surname +' '+ name}}" placeholder="<g:message code='patient.choose' default='Insert patient...' />"/>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Thanks!